# How to set MMX registers in a Windows exception handler to emulate unsupported 3DNow! instructions

Tags: c++, windows, exception, assembly, mmx

I'm trying to revive an old Win32 game that uses 3DNow! instruction set to make 3D rendering.

On modern OSs like Win7 - Win10 instructions like FPADD or FPMUL are not allowed and the program throws an exception.

Since the number of 3DNow! instuctions used by the game is very limited, in my VS2008 MFC program I tried to use vectored exception handling to get the value of MMX registers, emulate the 3DNow! instructions by C code and push the values back to the processor 3DNow! registers.

So far I succeeded in first two steps (I get mmx register values from `ExceptionInfo->ExtendedRegisters` byte array at offset 32 and use float type C instructions to make calculations), but my problem is that, no matter how I try to update the MMX register values the register values seem to stay unchanged.

Assuming that my `_asm` statements might be wrong, I did also some minimal test using simple statements like this:

```
_asm movq mm0 mm7
```

This statement is executed without further exceptions, but when retrieving the MMX register values I still find that the original values were unchanged.

How can I make the assignment effective?

Comment: So this game only ever ran on AMD hardware?  Intel CPUs have never supported 3DNow, so I'm surprised it doesn't have a code path that avoids 3DNow.  If you're on an AMD CPU, maybe it's mis-detecting and thinks you do have 3DNow, and your best be might be to hack the CPU-detection (look for `CPUID`).

Comment: So you're running `_asm movq mm0 mm7` inside your exception handler?  Shouldn't you actually be updating `ExtendedRegisters` in memory before returning from the exception?  I'd assume that returning from an exception handler replaces the current registers with the *saved* registers, so anything you leave in registers before returning is blown away.  (Designing the OS this way lets exception-handlers use the normal calling convention instead of having to save/restore *all* registers.)

Comment: I apologise if I possibly make some confusion between 3DNow! and MMX, The game is "Arthur's Knights: Tales of Chivalry" and is not targeted to AMD CPU only, but that seems to be the defaulted renderer for any CPU that answers with a positive MMX flag to a CPUID instruction with eax=1, like any modern CPU also from Intel. In effect the instruction set seems supported but disabled by OS: it is possible to run the game on same CPU but using a different OS like XP or Win95/98/ME.

Comment: Really?  Are you sure it's not also checking any other CPUID flags?  That would make it crash on any Intel CPU with MMX if that's really all it looks at.  Are you sure it doesn't check for `AuthenticAMD` in the vendor string as well?  But anyway, can't you just patch it to *not* detect MMX so it will use the fallback x87?  That will be faster than taking exceptions for every math instruction in a software renderer!  If you want it to be faster, consider rewriting some of the hot functions in C so a modern compiler can use SSE2 (and maybe auto-vectorize).

Comment: By the way, the game hack is targeted to be part of DxWnd and has a technical interest to me. I forgot to mention it, but updating the ExtendedRegisters structure was the first option, but it simply didn't work, changes in there were not reflected to the final registers value, so that's why I tried to force the result by using movq instructions.

Comment: Ok, well IDK how to modify main-program registers from an exception handler.  That's probably not MMX-specific and something you can look up in the MS docs.

Comment: It does check for AuthenticAMD but no matter what I return to CPUID with eax=0 it either uses MMX instructions or (sadly) uses a not working renderer. Another game of the same company was fixed by simply patching the answer to CPUID answer, but this one seems more complex (or bugged?)

Comment: About CPUID usage, the game has several instructions in the assembly, all used with eax=0 or eax=1. There is also a CPUID with eax=0x80000001, but on my Intel CPU it never goes through there. In the game there are also evident traces of other tricks to tell the difference from 8086, i386 or i486 CPU architecture, and spread in different and also duplicated places, to summarize it is a big mess, written before the idea that hw acceleration was to be bound to graphical drivers.

Comment: Ok, in your question you left out that it checks for AMD, and that the non-MMX fallback was buggy.  Maybe it works only for smaller screen resolutions or something using integer math?  Have you tried it on an Intel CPU (or if you're using a VM that lets you hack CPUID return values, just tried indicating non-AMD with MMX)?  OTOH, trying it with no VM at all might be a good idea.  IDK if that could interfere with 3DNow at all; I searched but didn't find anything about needing to set an "enable" bit anywhere, so IDK how Win10 is making your CPU trap on `PFMUL`.  (It's PFMUL not FPMUL)

Answer (score 5):

> On modern OSs like Win7 - Win10 instructions like FPADD or FPMUL are not allowed

More likely your CPU doesn't support 3DNow!  [AMD dropped it for Bulldozer-family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DNow!#Processors_supporting_3DNow), and Intel never supported it.  So unless you're running modern Windows on an Athlon64 / Phenom (or a Via C3), your CPU doesn't support it.

(Fun fact: [`PREFETCHW`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/prefetchw) was originally a 3DNow! instruction, and *is* still supported (with its own CPUID feature bit).  For a long time Intel CPUs ran it as a NOP, but Broadwell and later (IIRC) do actually prefetch a cache line into Exclusive state with a Read-For-Ownership.)

---

Unless this game only ever ran on AMD hardware, it must have a code path that avoids 3DNow.  Fix its CPU detection to stop detecting your CPU as having 3DNow.  (Maybe you have a recent AMD, and it assumes *any* AMD has 3DNow?)

(update on that: [OP's comments say that the other code paths don't work for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969423/how-to-set-mmx-registers-in-a-windows-exception-handler-to-emulate-unsupported-3?noredirect=1#comment80967195_46969423).  That's a problem.)

---

Returning from an exception handler probably restores registers from saved state, so it's not surprising that changing register values in the exception handler has no effect on the main program.

Apparently [updating `ExtendedRegisters` in memory doesn't do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969423/how-to-set-mmx-registers-in-a-windows-exception-handler-to-emulate-unsupported-3?noredirect=1#comment80967125_46969423), though, so that's only a copy of the saved state.

The answer to modifying MMX registers from an exception handler is probably the same as for integer or XMM registers, so look up MS's documentation for that.

---

Alternative suggestion:

**Rewrite the 3DNow code to use SSE2.  (You said there's only a tiny amount of it?)**.  SSE2 is baseline for x86-64, and generally safe to assume for 32-bit x86.

Without source, you could still modify the asm for the few functions that use 3DNow.  You can literally just change the instructions to use 64-bit loads/stores into XMM registers instead of 3DNow! 64-bit loads/stores, and replace PFMUL with `mulps`, etc.  (This could get slightly hairy if you run out of registers and the 3DNow code used a memory source operand.  `addps xmm0, [mem]` requires 16B-aligned memory, and does a 16 byte load.  So you may have to add a spill/reload to borrow another register as a temporary).

**If you don't have room to rewrite the functions in-place, put in a `jmp` to somewhere you do have room to add new code.**

Most of [the 3DNow instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DNow!#3DNow) have equivalents in SSE, but you may need some extra `movaps` instructions to copy registers around to implement `PFCMPGE`.  If you can ignore the possibility of NaN, you can use [`cmpps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpps) with a not-less-than predicate.  (Without AVX, SSE only has compare predicates based on less-than or not-less-than).

`PFSUBR` is easy to emulate with a spare register, just copy and `subps` to reverse.  (Or SUBPS and invert the sign with XORPS).  `PFRCPIT1` (reciprocal-sqrt first iteration of refinement) and so on don't have a single-instruction implementation, but you can probably just use `sqrtps` and `divps` if you don't want to [implement Newton-Raphson iterations with mulps and addps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555260/fast-vectorized-rsqrt-and-reciprocal-with-sse-avx-depending-on-precision) (or with AVX `vfmadd`).  Modern CPUs are much faster than what this game was designed for.

---

You can load / store a pair of single-precision floats from/to memory into the bottom 64 bits of an XMM register using `movsd` (the SSE2 double-precision load/store instruction).  You can also store a pair with `movlps`, but still use `movsd` for loading because it zeros the upper half instead of merging, so it doesn't have a dependency on the old value of the register.

Use [`movdq2q mm0, xmm0`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movdq2q) and `movq2dq xmm0, mm0` to move data between XMM and MMX.

Use `movaps xmm1, xmm0` to copy registers, even if your data is only in the low half.  (`movsd xmm1, xmm0` merges the low half into the original high half.  `movq xmm1, xmm0` zeros the high half.)

`addps` and `mulps` work fine with zeros in the upper half.  (They can slow down if any garbage (in the upper half) produces a denormal result, so prefer keeping the upper half zeroed).  See http://felixcloutier.com/x86/ for an instruction-set reference (and other links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

Any shuffling of FP data can be done in XMM registers with `shufps` or `pshufd` instead of copying back to MMX registers to use whatever MMX shuffles.

Comment: The game is a legacy one, "Arthur's Knights: Tales of Chivalry", so apart from some limited assembly patching I can't obviously rewrite parts of it, I'm not the developer of the game and I have no source code.

Comment: @gho: you could still replace the few functions that use 3DNow with your own that work exactly the same way but using XMM registers.  It shouldn't be too bad going through the asm and just locally changing each 3DNow instruction to an SSE equivalent, for a couple functions.  The common instructions can be substituted 1-for-1.